# Visual Foxpro 9 Odd behaviour with large numeric values

Tags: visual-foxpro

Can someone please explain this behaviour and suggest a way around it?

In the command window on VFP 9.

Test 1

a = 7003602346555440

? a

Displays correct value.

Test 2

a = 7003602346555438

? a

Still fine.

Test 3

a = 7003602346555439

? a

Displays incorrect value of 7003602346555440

Test 4

? a=7003602346555439

Returns .T. as you'd expect.

Test 5

? VAL(7003602346555439)

Displays incorrect value of 7003602346555440

Clearly something odd going on with converting the numeric into the textual representation for display, but can anyone suggest a way to avoid this and ensure I always get the correct text version of the numeric?

Comment: That appears to be due to numeric precision. I'm not sure if there is a work-around

Answer (score 3):

[Source from this article](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/259/Q259562/)

## SUMMARY

Visual FoxPro is documented as having 16 digits of precision. This is an
approximation: the actual maximum exactly representable number is
9007199254740992 (2^53).

## MORE INFORMATION

Floating point numbers are stored in 8-byte or 64-bit representations. There are
12 bits of overhead, leaving 52 bits to store the number. There is one more
implied bit that gives you 2^53 as the maximum. The maximum number that can be
stored by Visual FoxPro is 2^1023. The highest power of two that is printed out
exactly using the ? command with the default setting of SET DECIMALS TO 2 is
2^43.

The following code demonstrates this:

SET DECIMALS TO 2
  ? 2^43             && All digits displayed
  ? 2^44             && Scientific notation

SET DECIMALS TO 5
  ? 2^53             && Maximum exact number

? 2^53 - 1         && Correct result
  ? 2^53 + 1         && Incorrect result: rounded in floating point

? 2^1023           && Cannot display: *'s will be printed
  ? 2^1022           && Can display

Answer (score 0):

Even though the documentation says that val() will round up after 16 digits, it often rounds up at 16 **and** above.  The example you are showing uses 16 digits and that is causing val() to round up.